# Different colors for nodes in tree plot

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, color

I have some list of numbers which I am plotting using TreePlot.

This is the code:

```
Plotting[S_, u_, d_, n_] := 
  Module[{coor = Flatten[Table[Table[{i, j - 1 - i/2}, {j, 1, i + 1}], {i, 0, n}],
       1], 
         steps = Flatten[Table[ Table[
         {S*u^k*d^(l - k) -> S*u^k*d^(l - k + 1), S*u^k*d^(l - k) -> S*u^(k + 1)*d^(l - k)}, 
                         {k, 0, l}], {l, 0, n - 1}]]}, 
   TreePlot[steps, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
            VertexCoordinateRules -> coor, PlotLabel -> S]];

Plotting[S, u, d, 4]
```

And now, i need some of the nodes to be painted in different color. For example dSu, Su^3 and d^4S.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

One easy way is to replace the style of the specific nodes in the final tree. Let's make a function for it:

```
colorize[tree_, nodes_List] := With[{patt = Alternatives @@ nodes},
  tree /. Framed[p : patt, style_, r2___] :> 
    Framed[p, style /. c_RGBColor :> Darker[c], r2]
  ]
```

Now you can do

```
t = Plotting[S, u, d, 4];
colorize[t, {S, d^2 S*u^2, d^3 S}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Some explanation

To see how a single node is represented in the final graphics, you could look at the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputForm.html) of the final tree. There you see, that each node is a `Text` element:

```
Cases[t, Text[__], 5] // InputForm

(* ...
Text[Framed[S, {Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0.8], 
  FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0.94, 0.85, 0.36], 
  FrameMargins -> Automatic}], 1]
*)
```

Now you can go and replace all style settings you want. For a short example, I did nothing more than darken all found colors, but you are of course free to change it to whatever you like.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, just what i needed :) Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You could set up a dynamic `VertexRenderingFunction` that allows you to change the colors of your vertices with a click.

```
colorClickVRF[colors_List] := Function[{pos, name},
  Module[{i, len},
   i = 1;
   len = Length[colors];
   DynamicModule[{
     backColor = Lighter[First[colors]],
     frameColor = Darker[First[colors]]},
    EventHandler[{Text[Framed[Style[name, Black], 
        Background -> Dynamic[backColor],
        FrameStyle -> Dynamic[frameColor]], pos]},
     {"MouseClicked" :> (i = Mod[i + 1, len, 1];
        backColor = Lighter[colors[[i]]];
        frameColor = Darker[colors[[i]]])}]
    ]]];
```

Note that `colorClickVRF` accepts a list of colors and returns a function that is acceptable as either a `VertexRenderingFunction` for `GraphPlot` or `TreePlot` as you are using.  It also works as a `VertexShapeFunction` for the newer `Graph` and friends.  Here's an example.

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = RandomGraph[{10, 30}, VertexShapeFunction -> 
  colorClickVRF[{Yellow, Red, Lighter[Blue]}]]
```

[image]

When first generated, all nodes appear yellow.  The other colors you see were obtained by clicking on the nodes once or twice.  In your case, you simply need to add this same option to your call to `TreePlot`:

[image]

I originally set this up to help me color my NCAA tournament bracket near the bottom of this [math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710864/how-can-i-use-math-to-fill-out-my-ncaa-tournament-bracket).
Unfortunately, that was about the best thing that came out of that little project.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr = Plotting[S, u, d, 4];
vt = {S, d^2 S*u^2, d^3 S};
MapAt[# /. fr:Framed[Alternatives@@ vt, ___]:> MapAt[Darker, fr, {{2, 1, 2}}] &, tr, {1}]
```

or

```
pos = Join @@ (Position[tr, Framed[#, ___]] & /@ vt);
MapAt[Orange &, tr, Join[#, {2, 1, 2}] & /@ pos]
```

or

```
tr2 = tr;
(tr2[[Sequence @@ #]] = Orange) & /@ (Join[#, {2, 1, 2}] & /@ pos);
tr2
```

[image]